# How can I prevent AstroJS components from hiding SVG elements when the SVG is used in another file as client:load?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, astrojs

I'm building a weather app using Astro.js with React. I have a SVG component which is the logo of my project and is used in initial page loader. When the page loads, the SVG works as expected in the Loader.tsx file. But after the page loads, the same SVG which is used as Logo in the Header.astro component is invisible. The SVG is rendered to the DOM but is just invisible.

The Problem is solved if I removed the `<Loader client:load />` in Layout.astro, but I need the Loader.tsx component

Screenshot of Page Loader element (Blue Spinning fan is the SVG Logo)
[image: Screenshot of Page Loader element (Blue Spinning fan is the SVG Logo)]

Screenshot of SVG element inspect
[image: Screenshot of SVG element inspect]

[Full project source code repo](https://github.com/ChiragChrg/vortexa)

This is the LogoSVG.tsx file which is a vortex logo with a spin animation:

```js
type Props = {
    size?: string,
    className?: string,
}

const LogoSVG = ({ size = "50px", className = "" }: Props) => {
    return (
        <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 95 95"
            width={size}
            height={size}
            className={`animate-[spin_2s_linear_infinite_reverse] ${className}`}>
            <path
                fill="url(#paint0_radial_635_218)"
                d="M47.5 58.5C32.586 65.9 14.812 65.6 0 57.4c1.124 5 2.962 9.7 5.516 13.9 3.575 6 10.828 9.1 17.672 7.5 3.269-.7 6.436-2 9.5-3.7C39.43 71.3 44.64 65.5 47.5 58.5z"
            ></path>
            <path
                fill="url(#paint1_radial_635_218)"
                d="M62.516 2.3C57.817.8 52.71 0 47.5 0h-.102c-7.15 0-13.382 4.6-15.527 11.2-.92 3.1-1.532 6.4-1.532 9.9 0 7.7 2.656 15 7.355 20.9.919-16.3 10.112-31.2 24.822-39.7z"
            ></path>
            <path
                fill="url(#paint2_radial_635_218)"
                d="M32.484 92.7C37.183 94.2 42.29 95 47.5 95h.102c7.15 0 13.382-4.6 15.527-11.2.92-3.1 1.532-6.4 1.532-9.9 0-7.7-2.656-15-7.355-20.9-.919 16.3-10.112 31.2-24.822 39.7z"
            ></path>
            <path
                fill="url(#paint3_radial_635_218)"
                d="M79.473 46.2c-6.844-3.8-14.607-5.3-22.166-4.2C71.3 50.9 79.983 66.1 80.085 82.8c3.78-3.3 7.048-7.2 9.602-11.5 3.575-6 2.758-13.7-2.145-18.8-2.35-2.5-5.005-4.6-8.07-6.3z"
            ></path>
            <path
                fill="url(#paint4_radial_635_218)"
                d="M47.5 36.5c14.914-7.4 32.688-7.1 47.5 1.1-1.124-5-2.962-9.7-5.516-13.9-3.575-6-10.828-9.1-17.672-7.5-3.269.7-6.436 2-9.5 3.7C55.57 23.7 50.36 29.5 47.5 36.5z"
            ></path>
            <path
                fill="url(#paint5_radial_635_218)"
                d="M15.527 48.8c6.844 3.8 14.607 5.3 22.167 4.2-13.995-8.9-22.678-24.1-22.78-40.8-3.78 3.3-7.048 7.2-9.602 11.6-3.575 6-2.758 13.7 2.145 18.8 2.35 2.4 5.005 4.5 8.07 6.2z"
            ></path>
            <path
                fill="url(#paint6_radial_635_218)"
                d="M47.5 54.2c3.78 0 6.844-3 6.844-6.7s-3.064-6.7-6.844-6.7c-3.78 0-6.844 3-6.844 6.7s3.064 6.7 6.844 6.7z"
            ></path>
            <defs>
                <radialGradient
                    id="paint0_radial_635_218"
                    cx="0"
                    cy="0"
                    r="1"
                    gradientTransform="matrix(-2.55381 55.00004 -54.99505 -2.55358 47.5 47.5)"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                >
                    <stop stopColor="#00B0FF"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" stopColor="#06F"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient
                    id="paint1_radial_635_218"
                    cx="0"
                    cy="0"
                    r="1"
                    gradientTransform="matrix(-2.55381 55.00004 -54.99505 -2.55358 47.5 47.5)"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                >
                    <stop stopColor="#00B0FF"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" stopColor="#06F"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient
                    id="paint2_radial_635_218"
                    cx="0"
                    cy="0"
                    r="1"
                    gradientTransform="matrix(-2.55381 55.00004 -54.99505 -2.55358 47.5 47.5)"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                >
                    <stop stopColor="#00B0FF"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" stopColor="#06F"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient
                    id="paint3_radial_635_218"
                    cx="0"
                    cy="0"
                    r="1"
                    gradientTransform="matrix(-2.55381 55.00004 -54.99505 -2.55358 47.5 47.5)"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                >
                    <stop stopColor="#00B0FF"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" stopColor="#06F"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient
                    id="paint4_radial_635_218"
                    cx="0"
                    cy="0"
                    r="1"
                    gradientTransform="matrix(-2.55381 55.00004 -54.99505 -2.55358 47.5 47.5)"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                >
                    <stop stopColor="#00B0FF"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" stopColor="#06F"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient
                    id="paint5_radial_635_218"
                    cx="0"
                    cy="0"
                    r="1"
                    gradientTransform="matrix(-2.55381 55.00004 -54.99505 -2.55358 47.5 47.5)"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                >
                    <stop stopColor="#00B0FF"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" stopColor="#06F"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
                <radialGradient
                    id="paint6_radial_635_218"
                    cx="0"
                    cy="0"
                    r="1"
                    gradientTransform="matrix(-2.55381 55.00004 -54.99505 -2.55358 47.5 47.5)"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                >
                    <stop stopColor="#00B0FF"></stop>
                    <stop offset="1" stopColor="#06F"></stop>
                </radialGradient>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    )
}

export default LogoSVG.
```

LogoSVG.tsx is used here in Header.astro file

```js
---
import LogoSVG from "./SVG/LogoSVG";
import SearchBar from "./React/SearchBar";
---

<header
    class="flex gap-4 sm:justify-between items-center mx-4 my-2 px-2 py-2 overflow-hidden bg-black/20 backdrop-blur-md rounded-lg"
>
    <div class="flex_center gap-4">
        <LogoSVG size="40px" />
        <h1 class="hidden sm:block text-[1.25em] font-bold">VORTEXTA</h1>
    </div>

    <SearchBar client:load />

    <nav class="hidden sm:flex justify-center items-center gap-4">
        <a class="link" href="/">Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="/about">About</a>
        <a class="link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </nav>
</header>

<style>
    .link {
        @apply px-2 rounded text-[1.1em] hover:translate-y-[-0.25em] transition-transform;
    }
</style>
```

LogoSVG.tsx is also used in a Loader.tsx Component which is shown in initial load of the page:

```js
import { useStore } from '@nanostores/react'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { weather } from '../../store/weatherStore'
import CloudSVG from '../SVG/CloudSVG'
import LogoSVG from '../SVG/LogoSVG'

const Loader = () => {
    const $weather = useStore(weather)
    const LoaderRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if ($weather?.cod == 200 && LoaderRef.current) {
            const loaderElement = LoaderRef.current as HTMLElement;

            loaderElement.style.display = "none";
            document.body.style.overflow = "visible"
        }
    }, [$weather])

    return (
        <div ref={LoaderRef} className='absolute inset-0 w-screen h-screen bg-gradient-to-br from-blue-500 to-indigo-500 flex_center gap-[5em] z-10 flex-col'>
            <div className="relative flex_center">
                <CloudSVG className='absolute mr-[3em] mb-[3em]' />
                <LogoSVG size='120px' />
                <CloudSVG width='120' className='absolute ml-[4em] mt-[7em]' />
            </div>

            <div className="flex_center flex-col">
                <h1 className='text-[1.5em] font-bold tracking-widest'>VORTEXA</h1>
                <span>Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Loader.
```

This is the Layout.astro file where the Loader.tsx and Header.astro is used. Loader.tsx has attribute of client:load to load the react component in client browser. The LogoSVG file works correctly in Header.astro if I just comment out `<Loader client:load />` component, which solves my problem. But I need the Loader.

```js
---
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import Header from "../components/Header.astro";
import Loader from "../components/React/Loader";

interface Props {
    title: string;
}

const { title } = Astro.props;
---

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Astro description" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <title>{title}</title>

        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Initial Page Loader -->
        <Loader client:load />

        <Header />
        <slot />

        <!-- React-Hot-Toast Container -->
        <Toaster position="bottom-center" client:load />
    </body>
</html>

<style is:global>
    :root {
        --baseClr: #fff;
        --textClr: #fff;
        --lexend: "Lexend", sans-serif;
    }

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        background-color: var(--baseClr);
        color: var(--textClr);
        font-family: var(--lexend);
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .flex_center {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
</style>
```

#### Things I tried:

- I commented out the `<Loader client:load />` component in Layout.astro that fixed the problem and the Logo is visible in the Header.astro component.

```js
    <body>
        <!-- This is the initial Page Loader commented out below -->
        <!-- <Loader client:load /> -->

        <Header />
        <slot />

        <!-- React-Hot-Toast Container -->
        <Toaster position="bottom-center" client:load />
    </body>
```

- I also tried commenting out the `<LogoSVG size="120px"/>` in Loader.tsx and that also fixed the issue, but that means no logo in loader component :(

```js
<div className="relative flex_center">
    <CloudSVG className='absolute mr-[3em] mb-[3em]' />
    {/* <LogoSVG size='120px' /> */}
    <CloudSVG width='120' className='absolute ml-[4em] mt-[7em]' />
</div>
```

- I tried adding client:load attribute to `<Header />` component as well in Layout.astro file, but it didn't fix the issue

But I want the Loader component in the initial page load. So I want a solution without having to comment out the Loader component. Cant figure out the cause of this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after package.json update

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).